# Human readable duration format - Codewars

Tags: javascript

It's a task to build a String with time values and units, separated with `", "`

[link to Codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52742f58faf5485cae000b9a/train/javascript)

I'm stuck at the end. I wrote this code:

```
function formatDuration (seconds) {
    // return now if seconds = 0
    if (seconds == 0) {
      return "now";
    }
  
    // count values of each unit
    let Y = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
    let D = Math.floor(seconds / 86400 - Y * 365);
    let H = Math.floor(seconds / 3600 - D * 24 - Y * 8760);
    let M = Math.floor(seconds / 60 - H * 60 - D * 1440 - Y * 525600);
    let S = seconds - M * 60 - H * 3600 - D * 86400 - Y * 31536000;

    // build time values + units
    let YY = Y + " year";
     if (Y != 1) {
       YY += "s"
       }
    let DD = D + " day";
      if (D != 1) {
        DD += "s"
        }
    let HH = H + " hour";
      if (H != 1) {
        HH += "s"
        }
    let MM = M + " minute";
      if (M != 1) {
        MM += "s"
      }
    let SS = S + " second";
      if (S != 1) {
        SS += "s"
      }

    let timeDigits = [S, M, H, D, Y];
    let timeWhole = [SS, MM, HH, DD, YY];
  
    // check which units are not 0's
    let notZeros = [];
      for (let i in timeDigits) {
        if (timeDigits[i] != 0) {
          notZeros += i;
        }
      }
  
    // iterate notZeros through timeWhole and build the answer
    let format = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < notZeros.length; j++) {
      if (notZeros.length != 1) {
      
        // if it's the last unit
        if (j == notZeros[0]) {
          format = " and " + timeWhole[notZeros[j]] + format;
        }
      
        // if it's another unit
        else if (j != notZeros[notZeros.length-1]){
          format = ", " + timeWhole[notZeros[j]] + format;
        }
      
        // if it's the first unit
        else {
          format = timeWhole[notZeros[j]] + format;
        }
      }
      // if it's a single unit
      else {
        format = timeWhole[notZeros[j]];
      }
    }
    return format;
}
```

It works in most cases. on 100/110 tests made by Codewars results are green:

```
Test Passed: Value == '6 years, 192 days, 13 hours, 3 minutes and 54 seconds'
```

But on 10 of them I get this:

```
Expected: '4 years, 68 days, 3 hours and 4 minutes', instead got: ', 4 years, 68 days and 3 hours, 4 minutes'
Expected: '97 days, 10 hours and 26 seconds', instead got: ', 97 days, 10 hours and 26 seconds'
Expected: '33 days, 59 minutes and 55 seconds', instead got: ', 33 days, 59 minutes and 55 seconds'
Expected: '114 days, 46 minutes and 34 seconds', instead got: ', 114 days, 46 minutes and 34 seconds'
```

Problem is the ", " in the beginning of these, but I can't find any regularity in it.

Also on the failed test with Years unit, Hours and Minutes are shuffled.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier approach would be, instead of the whole last section, construct an array of strings - eg `['6 years', '192 days', ...]` - then pop the last off, join the rest by a comma, then add on `and` to the final one (if there's any of them other than the final one):

```
const Y = Math.floor(seconds / 31536000);
const D = Math.floor(seconds / 86400 - Y * 365);
const H = Math.floor(seconds / 3600 - D * 24 - Y * 8760);
const M = Math.floor(seconds / 60 - H * 60 - D * 1440 - Y * 525600);
const S = seconds - M * 60 - H * 3600 - D * 86400 - Y * 31536000;

const plural = num => num === 1 ? '' : 's';
const YY = Y ? Y + ' year' + plural(Y) : null;
const DD = D ? D + ' day' + plural(D) : null;
const HH = H ? H + ' hour' + plural(H) : null;
const MM = M ? M + ' minute' + plural(M) : null;
const SS = S ? S + ' second' + plural(S) : null;

const nonNullValues = [YY, DD, HH, MM, SS].filter(Boolean);
const last = nonNullValues.pop();
return nonNullValues.length === 0
  ? last
  : nonNullValues.join(', ') + ' and ' + last;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, there is a lot to learn for me here. But I still don't understand what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Doing `notZeros = []` but then `notZeros += i` means that it gets turned into a string, not an array. Then all the `if` `else`s inside the loop make the logic hard to understand and buggy given the non-intuitive reversed `timeDigits` and `timeWhole` indicies. I don't think the original code is worth fixing, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function formatDuration (seconds) {
  if(!seconds) return 'now';
    const units = {
    year  : 24 * 60 * 60 * 1 * 365,
    day   : 24 * 60 * 60 * 1,
    hour  : 60 * 60 * 1,
    minute: 60 * 1,
    second: 1
}
  const sequence = ['year','day','hour','minute','second']
  
  const calculateTime = (s) => {
     let remaningTime = s
     return sequence.reduce((acc,key) => {
       if(remaningTime >= units[key]) {
         acc[key] = Math.floor(remaningTime/units[key])
         remaningTime = (remaningTime % units[key])
       }
       return acc
     },{})
   }

  const displayUnit = (num,str) => `${num} ${str}` + ((num == 1) ? '' : 's')

  const displayString = (timeObj) => {
    let result = ''
    let lastResult = ''
    let objKeys = Object.keys(timeObj)
    if (objKeys.length <= 1) return displayUnit(timeObj[objKeys[0]],objKeys[0]);
    objKeys.forEach(v => {
      if (result && lastResult) {
        result += `, ${lastResult}`
      } else if(lastResult) {
        result += `${lastResult}`
      }
      lastResult = displayUnit(timeObj[v] , v)
    })
    
    return `${result} and ${lastResult}`
  }

    const obj = calculateTime(seconds)
    
  return displayString(obj)
  
}
```